# what happens to validation data after training completes?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

Not an ML expert but the normal flow I follow to train a machine learning model is after data cleaning, split the dataset to train, and test using scikit-learn's  train test split

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values,
                                                y.values,
                                                test_size=0.30,
                                                random_state=0)
```

skipping over the whole model building process...when you go to train the model(fit it) after defining and compiling it, it is to use the validation split parameter like below

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10,validation_split=0.2)
```

this seems to again divide the training datasets by 20% data points to validate our model during training. If you had let's say 1000 data points(rows) in a dataset the first code above will lead to
700 training data points for training and 300 for testing

the second will again divide that 700's 20% for validation leaving as
640 data points for training and 160 for validation

leaving us with small data to train our model with.

I recently encountered a method tho where you use the test data for validation like below

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

My question is what will actually happen to the validation data after training completes is it automatically added to train our model somehow improving our accuracy at the end and also is using the test data for validation enough and if we do that will it have an effect when we try to evaluate our model using the test data.

Comment: The data I'm using during training to validate the model, know the validation loss and validation accuracy during each epoch (using a deep neural network).

Comment: and also after retraining using both train and validation should we again retrain our model using the test data. in the end, prior to deployment? what will be the effects of that and will that depend on other factors?

Comment: When you let the model do a validation split for you it's unclear if the model will retrain validation data including. You should consult the docs for your model, and if it's unclear do validation split manually, and retrain later manually. Sklearn GridSearchCV will retrain (refit param), keras -- not so sure. If in doubt better do it by hand. You may retrain on test, if you know the labels, but in real life the definition of test suggests you do not know the labels (see Kaggle competitions eg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by `keras` (the last model.fit method with validation_data comes from keras)

> validation_split
>
> Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data to be used as
> validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the
> training data, **will not train on it**, and will evaluate the loss and
> any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The
> validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data
> provided, before shuffling.
>
> validation_data
>
> Data on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of
> each epoch. **The model will not be trained on this data**. This could be
> a list (x_val, y_val) or a list (x_val, y_val, val_sample_weights).
> validation_data will override validation_split.

**So with this setup, the model will not train on the validation data.**

In theory, validation data is used to evaluate your model and tune its hyperparameters.

If you need to put this model in production you should retrain the model with all the data, knowing that the performance would be what you obtained from the validation\test data

Anyway, the performances on validation\test data are often an optimistic estimate of the performance

[source](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html)